# Jquery - Extract string from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object, extract

using this code-snippet:

```
shownImg = $(".images img", selector).first().fadeIn(2000);
```

i get this this example-output in console:

```
Object[img thumb61h.jpg]
```

my question is:

How to extract the "thumb61h.jpg" from this object to save it in a variable?

Anybody know´s ?? Greetings!

Comment: var src = $(shownImg).attr('src');

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: or just shownImg[0].src - You don't need to initialize another jQuery object to get the source as it's available directly by the dom

Comment: @RajeshCP: Better: `shownImg.attr('src');`. `shownImg` is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
var src = $(".images img", selector).first().attr('src');
```

Comment: i need to get it from "shownImg" , otherwise "src" is undefined, you know an other way?

Comment: Umm I don't really understand it, why is `src` undefined, and why storing in `showImg` affects it?

Comment: @user3297073: That doesn't make sense. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the problem.

Comment: here is the scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/X9n6u/2/ , this line is important: if(shownImg) { console.log(shownImg) } , so what do u think?

Comment: @user3297073: I don't know where you get `undefined` from, but `var src = $(".images img", selector).first().attr('src');` is not `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/X9n6u/3/

Answer (score 0):

I played with your fiddle and it gave an alert with your image src

```
alert(shownImg.attr('src'));
```

Full fiddle code:

```
var shownImg;
function anim(selector) {
    $(".images img", selector).first().appendTo($('.images', selector)).fadeOut(2000);  
    shownImg = $(".images img", selector).first().fadeIn(2000);
    alert(shownImg.attr('src'));
    //var src = $(".images img", selector).first().attr('src');
}

// Untuk delay gambarnya
var i = 0, max = 3;
myFunction = function(event){
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});
    i += 1;
    if(i >= max) { i = 0; }
    //alert(shownImg)
    if(shownImg) { console.log(shownImg) }
}

var interval = setInterval(myFunction, 5000);

$(".slider").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    var img = $('<img>'); 
img.attr('src', $(this).attr('data-url'));
    $('#newImage').html(img);
    $('.images').hide();
    return false;
    i += 1;
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});

});

$(".slider").mouseout(
    function (){
        $('.images').show();
       // $('#newImage').hide();
interval =   setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
    }
);
```